# Word 2016- Deleting last and current sections one by one in RSCC VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

If I have a specific RSCC titled "General" with five sections (1,2,3,4,5), running the following macro2 deletes the last section leaving 4 sections (1,2,3,4).  If I keep running the macro, one by one, it becomes (1,2,3) then again (1,2) then stops at (1).  Perfect.

```
Sub Macro2()

'
Set repCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("General").Item(1)
Dim index As Long
For index = repCC.RepeatingSectionItems.Count To 2 Step -5
  repCC.RepeatingSectionItems.Item(index).Delete
Next index
 '
End Sub
```

However, if I were to add another two sections for a total of seven sections, running macro2 will delete the 2nd and 7th sections, then start deleting from the 6th section one by one.  For it to start deleting sections one by one starting with the 7th section only (not the 2nd), I would have to change the code from `For index = repCC.RepeatingSectionItems.Count To 2 Step -5` to `For index = repCC.RepeatingSectionItems.Count To 2 Step -7`

If I were to add another two sections for a total of nine sections, running macro2 will delete the 2nd and 9th sections, then start deleting the 8th section one by one.  For it to start deleting sections one by one starting with the 9th section only (not the 2nd), I would have to change the code from `For index = repCC.RepeatingSectionItems.Count To 2 Step -7` to `For index = repCC.RepeatingSectionItems.Count To 2 Step -9`

Question 1: How can I add and subtract sections randomly, run macro2 whenever and start deleting from the last section only (not the 2nd), one by one, back up to the 1st section so I don't have to manually edit the step with each change?

Question 2: How can I select any section and delete the selected RSCC only while the document is protected?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you do not understand how a `Step` value in a `For` loop works.

`For index = repCC.RepeatingSectionItems.Count To 2 Step -5` starts at the end and works backwards until it reaches 2. So for a collection containing *n* items it starts at *n* and goes back, *n*-5, *n*-10, etc until it reaches 2.

Apparently what you want to do can be summarised as:

If there are more than one RepeatingSectionItems delete the last one.

You need to use an `If` statement to do this, not a loop

```
Sub DeleteLastRepeatingSectionItem()
   Dim repCC As ContentControl
   Set repCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("General").Item(1)
   If repCC.RepeatingSectionItems.Count > 1 Then _
      repCC.RepeatingSectionItems.Item(repCC.RepeatingSectionItems.Count).Delete
End Sub
```

If your document isn't protected you can use the right click context menu to add and delete items.

[image]

There is no simple way to detect if the selection is within a `RepeatingSectionItem`, and as an RSI generally contains other ContentControls the code required to identify which RSI needs to be deleted isn't simple.

```
Sub DeleteSelectedRepeatingSection()
   Dim cc As ContentControl
   If Selection.Information(wdInContentControl) Then
      Set cc = Selection.ParentContentControl
      If Not cc.Type = wdContentControlRepeatingSection Then
         Do Until cc.Type = wdContentControlRepeatingSection
            Set cc = cc.ParentContentControl
         Loop
      End If
      'loop through the repeatingsectionitems to find the one that selection is in
      Dim rsi As RepeatingSectionItem
      For Each rsi In cc.RepeatingSectionItems
         If Selection.Range.InRange(rsi.Range) Then
            rsi.Delete
            Exit For
         End If
      Next rsi
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @TimothyRylatt- thanks for your help.  Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm trying to delete a selected section while the document is protected to only allow filling forms.

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - Please take time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64505591/edit) your question to include ***all*** relevant information.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt- Thanks again Timothy!  I have edited my question

Comment: @TimothyRylatt- Thank you sir!  Is there a way to delete a selected regular content control (not repeating) with a specific name (I would ask a new question of course)?